# Microsoft teams, send and receive messages in website without bot

Tags: node.js, socket.io, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Is there any way to send and receive messages asynchronously from a website to ms teams without bot intervention?

I have gone through Microsoft Graph API, there are some ms teams related APIs to read and send messages but those are synchronous apis.

Is there any way to implement socket programming or asynchronous APIs to send and receive?

Comment: MS Graph follows asynchronous programming. You can create a daemon app in the backend and use these [APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp).

Comment: Are you still looking for help?

Comment: Yes shiva, actually is there any way to implement a socket for getting ms teams chats and send messages?

Comment: Have you tried using incoming/outgoing webhooks? I think [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/what-are-webhooks-and-connectors) will help you to address your issue. Please let us know if you have any questions.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma are you still facing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Only available option to [read chat messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp) via APIs is using Microsoft Teams Graph APIs.

Microsoft Teams app supports one or all of the following core capabilities:

1. Tabs
2. Messaging extensions
3. Bots
4. Webhooks and connectors

Please take a look at [Understanding Teams app capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/capabilities-overview) documentation for more details. Please feel free to add new comment on answer if you need more details.